# Add structure to a hash ruby

Tags: ruby, merge, hashmap

I have a hash on the following way:

```
hash = {
    :k1 => number1,
    :k2 => number2
}
```

I need a simple way to transform it into:

```
hash = {
    :k1 => {:count => number1},
    :k2 => {:count => number2}
}
```

So I can merge it with other attributes.

Comment: Show us the code you wrote that didn't work. "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: Stack Overflow question checklist"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try something like:

```
hash.each {|k, v| hash[k] = {:count => v}}
```

Or, use the shorthand hash syntax:

```
hash.each {|k, v| hash[k] = {count: v}}
```

Comment: @ArupRakshit He said "transform it", and that seems to mean modify it.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, `Hash#map` converts a hash into an array, not a hash (because the `map` method has been included from `Enumerable`). Your simplest option may be this:

```
hash.each { |k,v| hash[k] = {:count => v} }
```

Comment: `Hash#map` can be handled as such `Hash[hash.map{|k,v|[k,{count:v}]}]` this will return the desired result `{:k1=>{:count=>23}, :k2=>{:count=>25}}`